# OPENCV Able to open the *avi, But unable to read frames from it

Tags: opencv, avi

I want to open a *.avi file and read its frames . But it didn't work . I think it's because myopencv don't support this kind of avi file. What can I do to make it capable?

```
VideoCapture capture("part.avi");
if(!capture.isOpened()){
    cout<<"failed to read the *.avi"<<endl;
    return -1;
}
double rate = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
Size videoSize(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
               capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
long nFrame=static_cast<long>(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));
cout<<"FPS:"<<rate<<endl;
cout<<"width:"<<videoSize.width<<" height:"<<videoSize.height<<" number of frames:"<<nFrame<<endl;
Mat frame;
namedWindow("display");
long frameToStart = 500;
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,frameToStart);
capture>>frame;
if(frame.empty()) return -1;
```

RESULTS:

FPS:23.0769

width:1280 height:720 number of frames:42202

Program ended with exit code: 255

Comment: Welcome to SO. So we can help you quickly, please give the question some context, tell us what you have tried already, and add an actual question.

Comment: I want to read frames for the avi file and it didn't work .

Comment: I want to open a *.avi file and read its frames . But it didn't work .
I think it's because myopencv don't support this kind of avi file.
What can I do to make it capable?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you read [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) first. It is not the problem of opencv but your code.
Videos are made of continous frames and you should place

```
capture>>frame;
if(frame.empty()) return -1;
```

within a loop like this:

```
while(1){
    capture>>frame;
    if(frame.empty()) return -1;
    imshow("display", frame);  //don't forget to show
}
```